# package longtable produces strange errors

Tags: longtable

Community,

I am writing a Paper in Latex for with the De Gruyter open style. In general I have a two-column Layout but i need to exclude two big tables that should be horizontal on full pages because they are quite big. As you can see in the code sample I used the `landscape` and the `longtable` environments for that.

```
\section{1}
\onecolumn
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.5cm} | p{4cm} | p{7cm} | p{9cm}}
& X & Y & Z \\
\hline \hline
1 & AAA \newline BBB & Lorem Ipsum & 
\begin{itemize}
    \item q
    \item r
    \item s
\end{itemize} \\
& X & Y & Z \\
\hline \hline
2 & DDD \newline EEE & Lorem Ipsum & 
\begin{itemize}
    \item t
    \item u
    \item v
\end{itemize} \\

\hline

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\twocolumn

\section{2}
```

I get a decent output but I also get many errors. They are all of the same kind:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<template> ...vtop \@startpbox {0.5cm}\@tablefont 
                                                  \ignorespaces 
l.74 &
       X & Y & Z \\
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Maybe you have an idea where to look for a solution or why those errors occur. I do not really have a clue at all. Since the .sty-file from De gruyter is quite large I do not include it here but if you think it is needed for solving the error it can be found here: http://www.degruyter.com/dg/page/59/production

I hope that you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Generally it's better to create complete documents demonstrating the problem, rather than snippets. Your error can for example be reproduced by a quite small document: `documentclass{article}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{3cm}}
a
\end{longtable}
\end{document}`. Without the `dgruyter` package the document works fine, so it seems to be conflicting with `longtable`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have an idea how to solve this conflict? I am quite new to Latex and I do not even know where to start.

Comment: If I knew I would have said so, I just wanted to highlight that small complete examples are better than isolated snippets for demonstrating a problem. If my example reproduces the problem on your system as well, you could always edit your question to include it in addition to/instead of your snippet.

Answer (score 6):

You could just put

```
\makeatletter
\def\@tablefont{\normalfont}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble to give this a default definition, however the class obviously intends you to use `supertabular` rather than `longtable` for long tables as that package is loaded already by the class file and `supertabular` as well as a standard `tabular` are patched by the class with code to support `\@tablefont`.

Unrelated but it's depressing to see the file is *still* distributed with

```
\p@=1bp\relax
```

at the top of the file, which pretty much breaks all LaTeX dimension calculations.